# Aws API Gateway SDK Generation for React Native

Tags: react-native, aws-api-gateway

We want to use the API Gateway SDK Generation (Javascript) in our React Native project.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html

Does anyone had converted the (Javascript) generation to (React Native) ?

Thanks
Francisco

Comment: Are you using AWS cognito for authentication and hope its not a public API?

Comment: I'd of thought the JS one would work fine no?

Comment: how did u end up on this?